# How do I make a navigation bar stay visible with UISearchController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

So I have a navigation controller hooked up to a view controller. That obviously provides the default navigation bar. Below that, I have another navigation bar with two buttons. In code I am manually adding the search bar that the UISearchController provides to that navigation bar.  Below that, there is another filter view (custom), then a UITableView. Everything seems to work, but when I click search and start typing, the result view covers up the second navigation bar and the search bar, making it sort of useless. I tried playing around with self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO; but that just hides the main navigation bar. The even more infuriating part is the result view controller is actually leaving space for the second navigation bar, but it's just hidden behind this. It is even possible to see this in the debug view heirachy menu. Here’s the code I'm using for the search controller:

```
CUSearchResultsTableViewController *results = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchResults"];  
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:results];  
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;  

self.searchBarNavItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;  
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;  
self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;  

self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;   
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;  
self.searchController.delegate = self;  
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Did you find the way how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

**objective-c**

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesSearchBarWhenScrolling:NO];
```

**Swift**

```
self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false;
```